# Why is my object offset from the Bezier curve?

Tags: objects, transforms, bezier-curves

I'm watching this [tentacle tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKfdy050JMQ) video. Most of it is working fine; I have a Bezier curve, my tentacle follows it, and so on.

However, I have one problem.

In the video, the tentacle is "around" the curve, as shown. The tentacle exactly follows the curve.

[image: video tentacle]

When I do it, it looks like this:

[image: my tentacle]

My tentacle seems to be translated away from the curve. This probably isn't a huge problem, but I would like to know why this is happening.

To clarify, I want to understand why the video's tentacles fit around the Bezier, but my Bezier is outside of the tentacle.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46250/problem-with-curve-modifier

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That can happen when the curve and the "tentacle" object do not share the same location.

Make sure the location (either under the *Object* tab of the properties window, or the properties region in the 3D view, accessed by <kbd>N</kbd>) are the same for both objects, curve and "tentacle."
[image: location of object]

If both are the same, in edit mode check that the mesh is at the object's origin. As the gif below shows, when the mesh is away from the origin, even both the curve and object show the same location it will still be off the curve.
[image: animated gif showing the offset from the curve]

Comment: The problem was with the origin; somewhere I must have moved it around. Thanks!