# Problem with curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

When I am in Edit mode, the curve modifier doesn't work but
when I go to Object mode, the curve modifier works but the object (the rail) moves to the left.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Here is the file: [image]

Comment: The **Curve** modifier works in Edit mode but it doesn't show the results of its work in that interaction mode. To show them use *Adjust edit cage to modifier's result*, see [interface of modifiers](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because the *mesh* and the *curve* haven't got the same ***origin point***. Select the curve, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*. Then select your mesh and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Selection to Cursor*.
[image]