# Why does the curve modifier cause the object to move to the left?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm having the same issue as user **A Allen** in: [Problem with curve modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46250/problem-with-curve-modifier)

> When I am in Edit mode, the curve modifier doesn't work but when I go to Object mode, the curve modifier works but the object (the rail) moves to the left.

I tried setting the same origin point to the curve and the object, which fixed the problem for him, but that didn't fixed the issue in my case. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Blender file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/qynzjxr4bxzs5h9/Hokkaido.blend/file

Comment: Please elaborate on how "the curve modifier doesn't work"/the issue. What is the desired result you're looking for? (maybe add a link to the page you quoted from) 
If i had to guess though, i think value of the Count in the Array modifier might be to low. Seems to me that if you were to increase that value the array would follow and cover a longer part of the curve.

Comment: @brockmann Link provided

Comment: @Fjoersteller It looks like it doesn't do anything in the edit mode and it moves the object towards -Z in any other mode

Comment: In order to show the modifier's effect in edit mode, you have to enable the second to the left icon in the modifier header that looks like a square with a bright dot in the upper right

Comment: And you can set the array length to "Fit Curve" if you don't want to guess the number count

Comment: Open the file you provided. Add a array modifier to the RoadSegement object. Make sure the Array modifier is above the Curve modifier in the modifier stack/list. (I suspect this is what might have gone wrong) and finally set the Count in the Array modifier to about 570. Does that work?

Comment: @Fjoersteller Yes it worked - I tried switching them around earler, but it was before I set the same orign point for the objects.
Thank you so much

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked : )