# Screw modifier not following spiral curve

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, bezier-curves, screw-modifier

My screw modifier is not following spiral curve the way I want it to. Im using **Curve Spirals > Archemedian** (from the extra curve addons).
I can best explain it with an image.
[image]

I do not want it to make itself thinner and fatter periodically, but cannot find a solution.
Thanks for helping.
EDIT: File for anyone that wants it: 
[image]

Comment: plz attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for detail inspection

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the mesh and the curve not having the same origin.
Once the objects are aligned, the spiral has constant width.

[image: spiral with constant width]

One way to make the objects share the origin is:

1. Select the curve, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and choose “Cursor to Selection”
2. Select the mesh, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, choose “Selection to Cursor”

Kudos to David for finding the solution for an [answer to a similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43572/34236)

Comment: Yea! Thanks that was really obvious and stupid at the same time haha BLENDER at it again. :>